# How can I detect a google login (with firebase) and close my login page sheet view on completion using swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, google-authentication

A button on my home page opens up a sheet view which displays a login screen containing a google login button (Code for this is below):

```
struct google: UIViewRepresentable{
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: GIDSignInButton, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<google>) -> GIDSignInButton {
        let button = GIDSignInButton()
        button.colorScheme = .dark
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController
        return button
    }

}
```

This is implemented in my login view with:

```
struct loginView : view {
    @Binding var logInShown : Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        google()
    }
}
```

What I need to know is how I can change `logInShown` to `False` after google sign in is complete.

I have tried the code bellow:

```
init(){
    _ = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        if (user != nil) {
            logInShown  = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you mention Firebase, have a look at the first snippet in this link on [getting the authenticated user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

Comment: How would I use it in this situation? I tried putting it in the init() function but trying to change the loginShown to false gave me the error of "escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter"